# Why my phone uploads so much data?

Tags: ios

I have an old iPhone 4S with the latest iOS. Reviewing my Unifi AP statistic I notice that my phone on average is sending about 40 MB/h, or about a megabyte of information by minute, even in a timeframe where I was mostly sleeping! I'm unable to determine to where the data was sent, since my router doesn't have such statistics, but as my phone is invariably old I would expect that this is a known behavior, but I haven't found any reason why my phone while inactive (ie. not moving or being used) was sending so much information upstream.

I know that I could blame any of the non-stock applications, but I don't restrict them on mobile (except for Spotify downloads), so I would have noticed by now such usage.

Comment: Check if you have iCloud backup turned on.

Comment: Do you have Google or Google Maps installed and have Location set to Always in Settings → Privacy for either app?

Comment: @NimeshNeema yes, I have it enabled. But apparently the latest backup occurred in the morning when I was awake. I will install a DPI system as soon as possible to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @grg Only google applications are Hangout and Authenticator.